Pass dates between SSRS reports
I have two SSRS reports. They are both accessing the same underlying table, aggregate or filter it and then display a table to the user. When I click on an Item Id in the table of the first report I want the second report to open and show data using the same parameters as were used in the first report.
Report 1 has 2 parameters. Date1 and Date2.
The underlying table stores snapshot data and report 1 compares this data for all items.
Report 2 compares the data only for one item.
When I click on an item in report 1 I want to pass Date1, Date2 and the item to report 2.
In both reports the Date1 and Date2 parameters are given a list of available dates which are drawn from the table containing the snapshots. This way the user has a dropdown to choose the dates he wants to compare.
I followed this tutorial about how to create drill down reports.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qk8BWLwGPI
It works for the item. It gets passed from report 1 to report 2.
But the dates do not get passed and when an item is clicked in report 1 there is still "Select a Value" displayed in the input fields of the date parameters in report 2.
I already tried to create hidden parameters with default NULL which don't use the dropdown. Then I set the dates with dropdown to be nullable and set their default to NULL. In the SQL code I overwrite the original date parameters with the hidden ones if they are not NULL. Then I passed the parameters from report 1 to the hidden parameters in report 2.
But it is still not working. I did this test because I guessed that the dropdown somehow interferes with passing parameters.
Do you have experience with typical problems when passing date parameters between SSRS reports? Please give me suggestions what I can try to solve this problem.

Best guess without seeing your report definition is that you are passing the dates in the wrong format.

If you are getting "Select a value" that likely means that the parameter value you passed wasn't in the permitted list.

A couple of things to try. 1. Remove the 'available values' for all parameters on report 2, unless report two can be access directly, you don't need them. 2. assuming you want the same dates passed and not the date of a selected item, pass the parameters from report 1, not the dataset values (e.g. Parameters!Date1.Value)

@DaleK: I pass "Parameters!Date1.Value" to report 2. Since Date1 is defined as datetime in report 1 and in report 2 it should already be the right format, right?

@ThomA: Both reports use the same query to define the dates in the permitted list. It's a "Select unique dates from dataset". Since the table changes only once per day. The lists should be the same.

@AlanSchofield: Report 2 can be accessed directly because it is convenient for users to have the ability. I could duplicate it but would like to avoid that. About your second advice: Good point. I am already doing that.

So is the parameter defined as a datetime in one report and a string in the other? That'll cause problems. Most likely the allowed values in one report will be formatted ISO dates 2024-09-16, while the latter would be implicitly converted dates and might have values like 'Sep 16 2024'. Unsurprisingly, '2024-09-16' and 'Sep 16 2024' are not the same.

@ThomA: It's the same in both reports.

@ThomA: Your comment gave me an idea. SSRS crops the miliseconds of datetimes from SQL Server when you use those datetimes as a dropdown for parameters. Maybe the dates I pass from report one are cropped to seconds and report two is comparing them to the original values with miliseconds. That would explain why it doesn't work. And I could fix it by changing my SQL statement for the values passed from SQL server to SSRS.

God, it worked -_-

So do your time parameters need to be accurate to 1/300th of a second?

@ThomA: No, it's not about the last millisecond digit only displaying 0, 3 and 7. All millisecond digits are cut by SSRS. If you pass this format from SQL Server "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:nnn" then SSRS crops it to "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss".

This sounds like you were using strings, not date times, in SSRS then. I have, personally, never had problems with passthrough parameters with date parameters (and I've been using SSRS for 12+ years).

@ThomA: Please see the question which I linked in my answer. The person answering there stated that cropping of milliseconds is a know issue of SSRS. He linked no source however.

When dates are passed to SSRS everything after the seconds gets cropped.
See this answer for reference: SSRS Report DateTime Parameters Do Not Support Milliseconds - Previews Correctly in Visual Studio But No Records in SSRS
When report 1 passes the parameter values to report 2 they are therefore cropped to seconds.
However, report 2 compares the dates to the original values from the database which are containing milliseconds.
If the cropping is already included in the SQL statements of both reports SSRS can do a successful comparison and report 2 gets passed the correct values.
Credits to the following community members who insisted on this being a formatting problem. They were proven to be correct.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127428/dale-k
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/thom-a
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775389/alan-schofield

